# Command line arguments ruby?

Tags: ruby

Hooray, its dumb question day! ;)

I know enough ruby to be dangerous but dont know a lot of basic foundational things. Can anyone direct me to some documentation or help me out with how to get my ruby code to take the first argument i throw at it (a file name) and store the filename in a variable? I've tried `ARGV[0]` and `ARGV.first`.

```
require 'mysql'
require 'nessus'

begin


filename = ARGV.first
scanTime = Time.now.to_i

Nessus::Parse.new(filename, :version => 2) do |scan|
....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#myprog.rb
p ARGV

fname = ARGV[0]
puts fname

puts File.read(fname)

--output:--
$ cat data.txt
John: a,123,b,456
Sally: c,789,b,0

~/ruby_programs$ ruby myprog.rb data.txt 10 hello
["data.txt", "10", "hello"]
data.txt
John: a,123,b,456
Sally: c,789,b,0
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are on the right track. `ARGV[0]` or `ARGV.first` is the right way to grab the first argument. I suspect that you are not sending/receiving the arguments properly. 
In that case, doing `p ARGV` will help you figure that out.

To see all the arguments you are receiving, do:

```
puts ARGV.inspect
```

or,

```
p ARGV
```

This will give you an array of arguments you pass. Like this:

```
➜ ruby test.rb foo bar baz
# => ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

Then, according to your need, do:

```
puts ARGV.first
puts ARGV.last
```

and save the file_name like this:

```
filename = ARGV.first
```

or,

```
filename = ARGV[0]
```

Here is doc for [ARGV](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#ARGV).

Comment: `puts ARGV.inspect` => Or, if you would rather do less typing: `p ARGV`.